# How to disable logs in Hive while writing to a file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a use case where i am executing hive query and storing output to a file.

```
hive -S -e "SELECT * from test.employee where empid=1"  > /mapr/Piyush/test/output.txt
```

The query is executing fine but i am getting logs also along with the data in the file. I am guessing it's because of the log4j properties. The problem here is i have no access to the log4j config file so i can't do any changes in it.
I tried setting couple of configuration like.

```
set hive.root.logger=ERROR, console
```

and

```
set hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

and

```
set hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled=false
```

But nothing helps. I need just the data from the table in the file. Please let me know if i am  missing anything or any solution to this issue.

Sample output file

```
2017-06-09 11:49:18,265 main ERROR Cannot access RandomAccessFile {}) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mapr/pankaj-hive.log (Permission denied)
2017-06-09 11:49:18,272 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender for element RollingRandomAccessFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:813)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:753)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:745)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:389)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:169)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.build(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.build(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:149)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:413)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:257)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:519)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:536)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:214)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:284)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager$RollingRandomAccessFileManagerFactory@48aca48b] unable to create manager for [/mapr/pankaj-hive.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager$FactoryData@13fd2ccd]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:61)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager.getRollingRandomAccessFileManager(RollingRandomAccessFileManager.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.createAppender(RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.java:206)
    ... 33 more

2017-06-09 11:49:18,277 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingRandomAccessFile in Appenders.
2017-06-09 11:49:18,281 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "DRFA" for logger config "root"
2017-06-09 11:49:19,640 main ERROR Cannot access RandomAccessFile {}) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mapr/pankaj-hive.log (Permission denied)
2017-06-09 11:49:19,644 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender for element RollingRandomAccessFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:813)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:753)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:745)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:389)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:169)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.build(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.build(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:149)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:236)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:445)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:140)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:98)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jDefault(LogUtils.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:646)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager$RollingRandomAccessFileManagerFactory@48aca48b] unable to create manager for [/mapr/pankaj-hive.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager$FactoryData@bff34c6]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:61)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager.getRollingRandomAccessFileManager(RollingRandomAccessFileManager.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.createAppender(RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.java:206)
    ... 34 more

2017-06-09 11:49:19,649 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingRandomAccessFile in Appenders.
2017-06-09 11:49:19,652 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "DRFA" for logger config "root"
1   piyush  bangalore   20
```

I want output as just

```
1   piyush  bangalore   20
```

Comment: I use this method sometimes, it works correctly for me. How is it that you are getting the logs in the file? Can you put a sample input and output?

Comment: hi added sample output file.

Comment: this directory/file `/mapr/pankaj-hive.log` is causing the error. Can you post your `hive-site.xml`

Comment: Have you tried this one: ``set hive.root.logger=ERROR, NullAppender``

Comment: HI Chemikadze, I tried but its giving same result

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per hive documentation **you can't change logging property by setting hive.root.logger via 'set' command** because hive reads the logger properties at time of initialization i.e prior to opening cli.

you can  do it like this:

**hive  --hiveconf hive.root.logger=OFF -S -e "SELECT * from test.employee where empid=1"  > /mapr/Piyush/test/output.txt**

P.S i have assumed that you don't want any logging. You can change logging level as per your requirement.

Below i am attaching screenshot of official documentation with link

[image]

[Click for official Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted)

Comment: Hi Anurag, as u suggest i tried putting --hiveconf instead of using set but still same issue.. One thing which i got by looking into the link given by you is we can't use SET here. But still not sure how to solve this issue as  including --hiveconf is not solving the issue

Comment: Let me try this for you with a dummy table

Comment: hi
hive -S -e "SELECT * from ris_170404.office where empid=1";
 This is working for me . I am getting this output 
1 emp addr 2016 12 01

try this command hive -e "SET". Check env variables

Comment: I mean check your environment variable by this command 'hive -e "SET" ' and check if logging variables are disable or not. If not disable them in this way hive -S -e ''SET disable env variable ; you command;"

Comment: Hi Anurag, I am getting those logs even if i am doing hive -help. So basically those logs are coming as soon as i am using hive -e/-f/-help/--hiveconfig  or anything. It might be working for you as for you u don't have configuration issues. The worst part is i don't have access to those configuration to even check what is the issue.